# Does Fallout 4 for PS4 limit the number of saved games?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

I just upgraded my PS4 with a 2TB internal hard drive, yet I cannot create more saved games because of some limit. I think I had 40 game saves (not including the game's few auto-saves) and Fallout 4 wouldn't let me create any new saves until I manually deleted some first.

Is that a PS4 infrastructure restriction on a game, to keep all games within some system-wide number of saves, or is it an arbitrary number imposed by the game?

Comment: What limit are you talking about?

Comment: VTLO; hardware limitations are not the same as game dev intent questions IMO. Though I do think the question could be clearer still. Edit: wait nvm, this is specifically about FO4 saves it seems. Anyway, it's still not related to mechanics or narrative.

Comment: @Schism Asking why there's a hard limit on number of game saves is developer intent, regardless of whether it's about mechanics or narrative.  At the end of the day, the only ones who can answer that are the developers.

Comment: @Frank I think that asking specifically about whether there exists some PS4-imposed restriction is fine. However, I agree that asking about why FO4 devs put in such a limit, if they did indeed choose to do, is off-topic.

Comment: @Schism I'm asking if it is a game mechanic or some other system imposed mechanic.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is a PS4 system restriction rather than a Fallout restriction (even if it's Fallout giving the message). I've read of similar problems in other games (Bioshock & Madden spring to mind) and in each it was the same - the game suddenly started reporting that there was no space to create another save even though their HDD was mostly empty, and the only way to solve it was by going into the system and manually deleting old saves.